# Htaccess redirect php files to html in root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I try to redirect the index.php plus system pages such as 404.php, 403.php etc. to their respective .html pages (index.html, 404.html, 403.html etc.) in the ROOT directory.

The problem is that the suggested solutions provided on Stackoverflow don’t seem to work in my case. Due to technical requirements, the PHP files have to stay in the root directory.

Rules in .htaccess

```
RewriteOptions inherit
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# -- concrete5 urls end --

<IfModule mod_headers.c>    
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
</IfModule>
#Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code at your main directory `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(index|404|403)\.php$   /$1.html [L,R=302]
```

The above code will redirect mentioned pages only in root directory and if want to add sub directory to any one of them , just change it like this `sub/index` or `sub/404` and so on.

I fit is ok , change `302` to `301` to get permanent redirection

Comment: It partly worked. Everything redirects to index.html now. However if I access a folder in the php related sub-directory (root/folder) it also redirects back to index.html in root instead of the index.php in that sub-directory.

Comment: i am sure it is only for root but you may have other rules in sub directory, wait let me revise it

Comment: it should work in root only , let me know if you have any rule in .htaccess to subfolder or at that subfolder

Comment: In the subfolder there is no .htaccess file. I did edit my original post with the content of the existing .htaccess file. Something in there probably interferes with your solution.

Comment: i think you use aptche 2.4 so , RewriteOptions inherit will apply the root rules to sub directory before any rules , get it out and clear your browser cache and test it